# Inline variable declaration outside of scope

Tags: c#, scope

Let's say I have two dictionaries with the same keys but with different values.

```cs
var metrics1 = new Dictionary<string, double>()
{
    { "Albert", 1.5513 },
    { "Becca", 3.3184 },
    { "Colton", -4.4001 },
    { "Danielle", 6.7 }
};
var metrics2 = new Dictionary<string, double>()
{
    { "Albert", 0.84156 },
    { "Becca", -6.7525 },
    { "Colton", 1.1102 },
    { "Danielle", 0.507944 }
};
```

If I then choose a dictionary at random to get a value from, using the ternary operator `?:`, Visual Studio says that I can inline declare a variable.

```cs
var rng = new Random();
var name = "Albert"; // Any name that's present in both dictionaries above

/* Unmodified code */
double metric;
var validName = rng.NextDouble() > 0.5
                    ? metrics1.TryGetValue(name, out metric)
                    : metrics2.TryGetValue(name, out metric);

/* After suggestion was applied */
// double metric;
var validName = rng.NextDouble() > 0.5
                    ? metrics1.TryGetValue(name, out double metric) // 'metric' is declared here?
                    : metrics2.TryGetValue(name, out metric);
```

Why is it that the `metric` variable in the modified version can be populated by both sides of the ternary `?:` operator? Should it not be contained entirely in the scope of the first branch?

Comment: No, the scope is not changed in this case. The important part is that the variable is definitely assigned after the statement has been executed, and in this case both branches of the ternary expression will definitely assign the variable. I see it as a slight quirk of the new syntax that you can inline the definition of the variable into the first branch, however.

Comment: Strangely, inlining the declaration in the right-hand side of the ternary operator is *not* allowed. If the scope doesn't change, shouldn't both sides of the operator be equally valid for variable declaration? Pretty cool feature, but mysterious nonetheless.

Comment: I don't have an answer to you other than that I've noticed the same. I assume this is because of a different rule saying that a variable has to be defined before being used. The two branches are not "parallel" in this case, they are sort of sequentially written and processed. I assume this is just how the C# compiler processes the expression and when it comes to the variable in the first branch, it sees it hasn't been defined and simply stops. However, all this is just conjecture on my part.

Comment: Close votes suggest a typo. There are no typos in the OP's code.

Comment: I suppose I could've simplified my question with a general `bool` instead of going with an enum and some elaborate plan to measure a useless metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer your comment, `// 'metric' is declared here?` first. Yes, `metric` is declared there (well... not technically... see below). To test this try to declare it in the second arm of the ternary statement; if you do this you get,

> error CS0841: Cannot use local variable 'metric' before it is declared

on the line containing the first arm. As to,

> Why is it that the `metric` variable in the modified version can be populated by both sides of the ternary `?:` operator?

Because the compiler compiles that code to IL that looks something like  the IL that would be generated for the previous code, **which means in both cases the declaration is above *both* arms of the ternary assignment.**

So for,

> Should it not be contained entirely in the scope of the first branch?

the answer is no, because in both cases the declaration is in the scope of the method above the ternary assignment that is also within that scope.

Essentially, the second implementation is just [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for the first.